# Text file representing nested structure to nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a text file representing multiple different nested structures, here is an example of two.

```
order product product_X
 enabled     true
 description smartphone
 specific routing Y
  service service A
  instance Yes
 routing ip 0.0.0.0
  address ipv4 0.0.0.0
  address-family 0.0.0.0
  neighbor x.x.x.x
   advertise              true
   remote-as              0
  neighbor y.y.y.y
   peer-type              external
   address-family         0.0.0.0
 ip                       0.0.0.0/0

order product product_Y
 enabled     true
 description smartphone
```

The logic is as follows

- The nested level is known by number of left spaces.
- If the number of spaces increases from the line before, it means the line before is the parent level.
- If the key has 0 spaces to the left, it means it is a new table.
- The value is the right most space separated part of the string.
- If a key exists multiple times at same nested level, its nested structure should be stored in a list.
- If a key has a nested structure below it, its value should stored in a field called "name" one level below.
- I do not know beforehand what the names of the fields will be in each table.

So the above file should be transformed to

```
{
 'order product': [
                   {
                   'name': 'product_X',
                   'enabled': 'true',
                   'description': 'smartphone',
                   'specific routing': {
                                         'name': 'Y', 
                                         'service': 'A', 
                                         'instance': 'Yes'
                                       },
                   'routing ip': {'name': '0.0.0.0',
                                 'address ipv4': '0.0.0.0',
                                 'neighbor': [
                                              {'name': 'x.x.x.x', 'advertise': 'true', 'remote-as': 0},
                                              {'name': 'y.y.y.y','peer-type': 'external','address-family': '0.0.0.0'}
                                              ]
                                 },
                  'ip': '0.0.0.0/0'},
                     {
                   'name': 'product_Y',
                   'enabled': 'True',
                   'description': 'smartphone'
                     }
                     ]
  }
```

I don't really know how to tackle the problem, so if anyone could give me some tips, hints or even if you have solved something similar, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are the column names consistent throughout the file? For example, does every level 0 some of the columns [['name', 'enabled', 'description', 'specific routing']]?

If so you could try regular expressions. Ie. something like:

```
order_idx = []

for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    if 'order product' in line:
        order_idx.append(idx) 
    else:
        pass
    chunk_text = ''
            
    for line in chunk:
        chunk_text = chunk_text + '\n' + line
    
    if re.findall('enabled\s(.*?)\s', chunk_text) != []:
        d['enabled'] = re.findall('enabled\s(.*?)\s', chunk_text, re.MULTILINE)[0]
    else:
        pass
        ...
```

Then rinse and repeat with a regex and dict key-value pair for every column and sub-column.

Comment: Unfortunately I would not know the fields beforehand.

Comment: Could you count repeated words and or n-grams with a loop? Ie. if the phrase "routing ip" shows up a bunch in the doc, then you could infer it's a column.

Comment: i think line by line is the way to go, but some logic must be created.